# Is it a dependency Injection anti-pattern a base class with many constructors?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I thought about doing a base class to centralize all properties that can be used in the child classes when needed.

My question is whether what I'm doing is an dependency Injection anti-pattern.

If so, could you give examples of what would be best to maintain the dependency injection pattern and SOLID principles?

Base Class

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        protected readonly IProductRepository _productoRepository;
        protected readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
        protected readonly IImageRepository _imageRepository;

        public BaseClass(IProductRepository productoRepository)
        {
            _productoRepository = productoRepository;
        }

        public BaseClass(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
        {
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }

        public BaseClass(IImageRepository imageRepository)
        {
            _imageRepository = imageRepository;
        }
    }
```

Product child class

```
public class ProductClass : BaseClass
    {

        public ProductClass(IProductRepository productoRepository) : base(productoRepository)
        {

        }

        public ProductClass(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository) : base(categoryRepository)
        {

        }

        public ProductClass(IImageRepository imageRepository) : base(imageRepository)
        {

        }

    }
```

Category child class

```
public class CategoryClass : BaseClass
    {
        //Only this constructor will be required in this class
        public CategoryClass(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository) : base(categoryRepository)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you for your attention to this matter!

Comment: I don't see the advantage of all of that boilerplate, just to define a single field. Why not put the field directly in `CategoryClass`? That way you don't have a bunch of fields floating about in some mandatory base class, most of which will (confusingly) be `null`

Comment: So your base class requires one of three different repositories?  This almost certainly violates SRP, LSP and possibly a few other principles.

Comment: When most people do this, their base class has all of the dependencies available all of the time. So it's just a service locator, but with the added disadvantage of forcing you to use a particular base class. You seem to be going on step further, and creating a sort of service locator which provides `null` for most of its services, most of the time. I can't see any advantage to that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you shared, there does not seem to be a justification for the use of inheritance to start with.

DI and IOC are not at odds with inheritance patterns, but SRP is clearly violated in your base class.

Comment: It's good to know that! 
My vote (up) doesn't change your publicly displayed post score yet! :-( 
I appreciate your attention!!!

Comment: @EvertonSolon thanks, it's frustrating to get downvoted without explanation, but I agree that the question is a bit opinion-based and it requires guessing a bit on the context of this. In general, repositories should be completely independent of each other. By SRP in this context I mean the base class has "reasons to be altered".

Answer (score 0):

Since a class can only be instantiated once, you will not have a DI call multiple constructors on your BaseClass to inject additional repositories post-creation.
I suspect what you really want in your `BaseClass` is to rather have **all** repositories that you need initialised at the same time:

```cs
public class BaseClass
    {
        protected readonly IProductRepository _productoRepository;
        protected readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
        protected readonly IImageRepository _imageRepository;

        public BaseClass(IProductRepository productoRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IImageRepository imageRepository)
        {
            _productoRepository = productoRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
            _imageRepository = imageRepository;
        }
```

this makes it for very standard and sensible way to set yourself up for dependency injection.

If you indeed wanted to have one different repo instance per class, then you might be better off Introducing a more generic `IRepository` and having it DI'd instead:

```cs
public class BaseClass
    {
        protected readonly IRepository _repository;

        public BaseClass(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository= repository;
        }
```

if you want to have a bit more control over what implementations you will need in your derived classes, you can opt for generics:

```cs
public interface IRepository { }
public interface IProductRepository : IRepository { } // you can inherit interfaces
public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository { }
public interface IImageRepository : IRepository { }

public class BaseClass<TRepo>  where TRepo : IRepository // we will require all generic parameters to be descendant of base interface
{
    protected readonly TRepo _repo;

    public BaseClass(TRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
}

class Category : BaseClass<ICategoryRepository> {

    public Category(ICategoryRepository repo) : base(repo) {} // DI will inject a specific implementation
}
```

hopefully the outlined examples are applicable to you